# Is there a limit on the number of indexes that can be created on Elastic Search?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using AWS-provided Elastic Search.

I have a signup page on my website, and on each signup; a new index for the new user gets created (to be used later by his work-group), which means that the number of indexes is continuously growing, (now it reached around 4~5k).

My question is: is there a performance limit on the number of indexes? is it safe (performance-wise) to keep creating new indexes dynamically with each new user?

Comment: According to this answer you should avoid it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64801934/518153

Answer (score 4):

Note: I haven't used AWS-Elasticsearch, so this answer may vary because they have started using open-distro of Elsticsearch and have forked the main branch. But a lot of principles should be the same. Also, this question doesn't have a definitive answer and it depends on various factors but I hope this answer will help the thought process.

One of the factors is the number of shards and replicas per index as that will contribute to the total number of shards per node. Each shard consumes some memory, so you will have to keep the number of shards limited per node so that they don't exceed maximum recommended 30GB heap space. As per [this comment](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/max-number-of-indices/97932/2) `600 to 1000` should be reasonable and you can scale your cluster according to that.

Also, you have to monitor the number of file descriptors and make sure that doesn't create any bottleneck for nodes to operate.

HTH!

Answer (score 4):

Indexes themselves have no limit, however shards do, the recommended amount of shards per GB of heap is 20(JVM heap - you can check on kibana stack monitoring tab), this means if you have 5GB of JVM heap, the recommended amount is 100.

Remember that 1 index can take from 1 to x number of shards (1 primary and x secondary), normally people have 1 primary and 1 secondary, if this is you case then you would be able to create 50 indexes with those 5GB of heap

Answer (score 3):

If I'm not mistaken, the only limit is the disk space of your server, but if your index is growing too fast you should think about having more replica servers. I recomend reading this page: [Indexing Performance Tips](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/indexing-performance.html)

Comment: I'm not asking about the single-index-size-limit, my question is about a limit on the number of created indexes.

Comment: Maybe this helps... http://grokbase.com/t/gg/elasticsearch/14331g01pk/maximum-number-of-indices-per-machine#201403033x6sgwwcjvne3vtmdfipkvdm64

Comment: the elasticsearch cluster itself doesn't have the limitation, you can look at the 'total_shards_per_node' and 'total_shards_per_node' config(see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/allocation-total-shards.html), it's defaultly set to unbound. but the server disk space and file description number will effect the cluster performance and limit the index size.