# Elasticsearch maximum index count limit

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6.5

Is there any limit on how many indexes we can create in elastic search?

Can 100 000 indexes be created in Elasticsearch?

I have read that, maximum of 600-1000 indices can be created. Can it be scaled?

eg: I have a number of stores, and the store has items. Each store will have its own index where its items will be indexed.

Comment: People who are not from India aren't likely to understand your issue if you use Indian words in it.

Comment: Ohh thank you for the edit, will keep it in mind :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no limit as such, but obviously, you don't want to create too many indices(too many depends on your cluster, nodes, size of indices etc), but in general, it's not advisable as it can have a server impact on cluster functioning and performance.

Please check [loggly's blog](https://www.loggly.com/blog/nine-tips-configuring-elasticsearch-for-high-performance/#:%7E:text=If%20you%20have%20too%20many,point%20of%20making%20it%20unusable.&text=If%20you%20have%20a%20year%27s,8760%20indices%2C%2043800%20shards) and their first point is about proper provisioning and below is important relevant text from the same blog.

> ES makes it very easy to create a lot of indices and lots and lots of
> shards, but it’s important to understand that each index and shard
> comes at a cost. If you have too many indices or shards, the
> management load alone can degrade your ES cluster performance,
> potentially to the point of making it unusable. We’re focusing on
> management load here, but running too many indices/shards can also
> have pretty significant impacts on your indexing and search
> performance.
>
> The biggest factor we’ve found to impact management overhead is the
> size of the Cluster State, which contains all of the mappings for
> every index in the cluster. At one point, we had a single cluster with
> a Cluster State size of over 900MB! The cluster was alive but not
> usable.

**Edit: Thanks @Silas, who pointed that from ES 2.X, cluster state updates are not that much costly(As the only diff is sent in update call).** More info on this change can be found on [this ES issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/6295)

Comment: In more recent versions of ES, cluster state is not such as issue as it was in 2016 (when the article was written) when the entire cluster state was being transferred to all nodes on every little change to the cluster, which could render the cluster completely unusable. Keeping the size down, is still a good general recommendation though.

Comment: @SilasHansen, thanks I agree, but could you point out to recent article which describe now on what basis cluster state is broadcast to all the nodes?? adding a new index make changes to cluster state which still needs to be broadcast correct??

Comment: yes that's logical and correct.
But the reason I am creating a different index is, other store documents interfere with the store I want to search in. The score is evaluated based on all the documents.

And the search results vary for instance by instance if I copy the store from one instance to other where there is no other store data or less data.

Comment: @jbmyid, I get your point, but there is a better way to handle it based on your use-case, I would suggest asking a separate question which focuses on improving your design based on your use-case, you need to provide details like the number of data nodes, their size, total stores aka indices, avg number of docs, number of shards and replica etc

Comment: @ElasticsearchNinja thanks.
I have already asked one question for the same issue. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64747474/how-to-calculate-score-after-filter-in-elasticsearch

I am not able to get anything anywhere.

Comment: @ElasticsearchNinja This [issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/6295) is where the diff conversation started and it became part of ES 2.0.0 which was released on October 28, 2015. It's hard to know if the loggly authors were burned (as many of us) from bad experiences with 1.x and didn't know about the update or not.

Comment: @SilasHansen, thanks a lot for the link, it was amazing that shay banon himself  issue, however few months ago, I found few posts on Stackoverflow where users reported timeout while updating the cluster state(crossed 30 second timeout) and they were on 6.x and 7.x, which made me think that this issue still exist.

Comment: @SilasHansen, I have updated the answer with your link, pls review and feel free to add more info , also please don't forget to update if you think answer is helpful, TIA :)